# Do cache block replacement policies in x86 prefer clean blocks over dirty blocks?

Tags: x86-64, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, micro-architecture

Does cache block replacement policies in x86 systems prefer clean blocks over dirty blocks? I am interested to know whether cache-line flush instructions such as `clwb` influence the cache replacement policy since `clwb` retains the block in clean state in cache.